# Вопрос по iframe, сессиям

Tags: битрикс, cookie, сессия, iframe, crm

Пишу приложение для облачной CRM Битрикс24. Идея такова - когда пользователь открывает приложение в окне CRM, в iframe подгружается мой сайт. И параллельно такая же схема действует для другой CRM - Amo.

Нужно сделать так, чтоб если сайт открыт в битриксе - отображалась бутстраповская кнопка, если же сайт открыт в AmoCRM или просто во вкладке - не отображать эту кнопку.

У меня была идея привязаться к сессии. Т.е. когда сайт открывается в iframe добавляю в сессию например 'bitrix' = 1 и показываю кнопку. Но проблема в том, что если открыть в соседней вкладке сайт, то и там будет в сессии 'bitrix' = 1 и кнопка соответственно будет отображаться.

Может у кого есть идеи, а то уже мозг кипит ((.

Answer (score 1):

А если при загрузке iframe передавать в get какой-нибудь параметр? А на сайте уже проверять параметр и отображать кнопку если он присутствует